# xsl:function doesnt work (adding two parameters and returning result)

Tags: function, xslt-2.0

```
<xsl:function name="sh:testfunc2" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="param2" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="param3" as="xs:integer"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$param2+$param3"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

called by

```
<xsl:value-of select="sh:testfunc2(1,2)"/>
```

Doesn't return anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well I would certainly use `<xsl:sequence select="$param2 + $param3"/>` instead of `value-of` inside the function but if you need more help then please post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem easily, also tell us which XSLT 2.0 processor you have used.

Comment: sorry, frustrating news: I got it now. The error was not in the function after all. There was an error in the way I called the template containing the function... But out of curiosity: Why would you opt for xsl:sequence?

Comment: `value-of` creates a text node while you want to add two integers and return an integer so in that case already having to integers and wanting to return the result of the expression `$param2 + $param3` using `sequence` is the natural way of achieving that, in my view. Having the `as="xs:integer"` on the function ensures that the text node the `value-of` creates is converted to an integer finally but I prefer using `sequence` instead of `value-of` in functions if I want to return the result of a certain expression.

Comment: allrighty, thanx for that explanation! much appreciated